# How to query redshift SUPER for non empty objects

Tags: redshift

**Context:**

I have a column called `event_properties` which has a lot of values of `{}` which is a redshift SUPER datatype. A lot of values are of empty object such as:

[image: empty event properties]

**Objective:**

Filter out values that aren't an "empty object"

**What I've Tried**:

- casting as ::text, will result in null values
- the `len` (length) function is not supported for SUPER type

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

(the queries below don't work, but should demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish)

```
select event_properties from native_app_events where event_properties::text != '{}'
select event_properties from native_app_events where len(event_properties) > 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
from native_app_events
where event_properties is not null
and json_serialize(event_properties)  != '{}'
```